# Robot Framework | Upload a photo to chat application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am facing the following issue: I have a task to send a file by automated script made by robot framework, I've done a plenty of research but found no result on this.

The thing is that the file should be uploaded to a chat application.

I have tried pressing the popup when pressing the upload button but with no success.

Only thing I need is somehow upload that image to the chat.

After I press the following button [File sending button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oiGv.png)

It will open a my finder so I will select a file, and I can't make robot framework to select it from my pc.

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am sorry @AjeetVerma I'll do my best to edit it now